# Firefox extension to track network requests across tabs

Tags: firefox, network-monitor

Can anyone recommend a Firefox extension that allows the user to track network requests across tabs?

In other words, let's say you are in Firefox, and you right-click on [this link](http://www.goodnewsnetwork.org/) and select `Open Link in New Tab`.  In order to verify that the link really went directly to the GoodNewsNetwork, you fire up your trusty Firefox extension (the one you recommend here) to quickly see that there was no redirection.

Normally, this could be done with the Developer Tools, but the network monitor in Developer Tools does not track requests across tabs (or, if it does, please tell me I'm mistaken!).

Now, obviously, this example is a bit contrived.  You could simply open the above link in the same tab.  But often sites are coded to open links in new tabs, which prevents monitoring network requests using the integrated Developer Tools.

Note that a tool outside of Firefox could be used (such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)), but I'm looking for something that runs within Firefox.

Recommendations for gratis extensions are preferred, but recommendations for paid extensions are fine as well.

Comment: Please have a look at this answer. http://superuser.com/questions/242138/how-to-track-url-redirects-in-the-browser .

Comment: @AswinPJ Good find, thank you.  But unfortunately, none of those solutions will work for links that are coded to open in a new tab.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard this is somewhat a hack! But if you don't get an answer, one way to do it is to right click and inspect the link, and look for a bit of code that looks like this `target="_blank"`, and delete it out of the `<a>` tag. So `<a href="google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>` goes to `<a href="google.com">Google</a>`. Then click on the link, and it will open in the same tab ;)

Answer (score 1):

I still cannot comment, so I have to give it a try with an answer:

I don't know a dedicated extension, but the "uBlock Origin" adblocker (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) has such a feature.

Just open its protocol of network requests!
The protocol is sorted by Firefox tabs and this works for every situation I just tested. Forced new tabs and user controlled new tabs as well.
I do not know if it contains every detail you wished for but it looks quite comprehensive.